# Error retrieving a list of your S3 buckets from AWS:Access Denied wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have get this error in wordpress: `Error retrieving a list of your S3 buckets from AWS:Access Denied`. I have write policy for IAM user. I don't know where I am doing wrong. Please help me.

My IAM policy is here:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmtxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, in order to list all your buckets, you need to create a statement that will allow your IAM to perform "s3:ListAllMyBuckets" in the entire S3 account

`{
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {}
}`

Also, it's seems like you have trouble with bucket listing because the actions that you are trying to allow:

`"Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
      ],`

must be applied to the entire bucket:

`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",`

while you are trying to allow this actions to the bucket's content:

`"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/*",`

Anyway, please try the policy below:

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Stmtxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation",
        "s3:ListBucket",
        "s3:ListBucketMultipartUploads"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname",
      "Condition": {}
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}`

I tested it on my site and it works.

If you have any other questions, feel free to ask.

Thanks,
Vlad

Comment: thnak you. Actually I forget to give user a administrative access. Now all works fine.